# Reverse For loop Crashes

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have this code and it crashes xcode

```
void strrev(const std::string& str)
{
    for(size_t i=str.length();i>=0;i--)
    {
        std::cout << str[i];
    }
}
```

It works fine if I do `i>0` but then the first character does not get printed
Any suggestions on what is wrong with `i>=0` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problem

`i` is of type `size_t` (it is an unsigned integral), so when `i` is zero and `i--` is performed, its value *wraps around*, getting `i` the highest possible value it can store. This `i` is then used in the expression `str[i]` causing a crash.

#### Solution

You can separately handle the case for `i` equal to zero. Also, since indices start at zero, the highest possible index is `str.length()-1`.
It should be then:

```
for(size_t i=str.length()-1; i > 0; i--)
    std::cout << str[i];
std::cout << str[0];
```

#### Recommended alternatives

Consider using *reverse iterators* instead to avoid having to deal with indices:

```
void strrev(const std::string& str)
{
    for (auto rit = str.rbegin(); rit != str.rend(); ++rit)
        std::cout << *rit;
}
```

Note that you can also use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) in combination with reverse iterators and a [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) object for `std::cout`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

void strrev(const std::string& str)
{
   std::copy(str.rbegin(), str.rend(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string::value_type>{std::cout});
}
```

or directly use [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) instead of `std::copy` and therefore no need for reverse iterators:

```
std::reverse_copy(str.begin(), str.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<std::string::value_type>{std::cout});
```

Comment: I fixed the code and used ``for(size_t i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)`` When i try this function with `strrev(std::string("Hello"))` the for loop doesnt exit after 0 ? Any idea why the for loop doesnt exit when its less than 0 ?

Comment: @MistyD `size_t` is an unsigned integral type, when would it be less than 0? Your compiler should be warning you of this. Turn up the warning level if it isn't.

Comment: Note that `std::string` also provides reverse iterators, eliminating the need to worry about indexing.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah I know i was just testing this out

Comment: This answer needs to mention the underflow that caused the OP's crash.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to do this in an idiomatic, index-free way using [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello World!";
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str << "\n"; // !dlroW olleH
}
```

Comment: I would also consider `std::copy`ing into `std::cout` with reverse iterators

Answer (score 0):

Since the strings in c++ are base zero -the first character in a string is str[0]- therefor the index of the last character in a c++ string is always str.length()-1 or str.size()-1
So it should be

```
void strrev(const std::string& str)
{
    for(size_t i=str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        std::cout << str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't that clarified enough in the other answers?